# Unexpected result of product of 2 double variables

Tags: java, double, floating

```
double price = 4.35; 
double quantity = 100; 
double total = price * quantity;   // Should be 100 * 4.35 = 435.00 
System.out.println(total); // Prints 434.99999999999999
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `price * quantity;` is not sum.

Comment: @RohitJain where OP uses *sum*?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:- In the questions' title!

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication is working fine, but 4.35 cannot be represented exactly as a double.

Check the [floating point Internal Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number#Internal_representation).

Wiki says:-

> The fact that floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all
>   real numbers, and that floating-point operations cannot precisely
>   represent true arithmetic operations, leads to many surprising
>   situations. This is related to the finite precision with which
>   computers generally represent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Because precision for a double is like something like:

> Double-precision floating-point format is a computer number format
>   that occupies 8 bytes (64 bits) in computer memory and represents a
>   wide dynamic range of values by using floating point. Computers with
>   32-bit storage locations use two memory locations to store a 64-bit
>   double-precision number (a single storage location can hold a
>   single-precision number). Double-precision floating-point format
>   usually refers to binary64, as specified by the IEEE 754 standard, not
>   to the 64-bit decimal format decimal64.

So your value 4.35 is not exactly stored as 4.35, rather it is stored with precision

**Source: Wiki**

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)